# How to call a function with a list and one other argument in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, find

My goal is to make a small program/macro in VBA Excel that fixes column names automatically. The way I would like to do this is having `Subs` for each individual column name `cell`. Each of these `Subs` has an `Array` of Strings, which contain the keywords that will be searched. If the cells value is exactly one of the Strings, the value will be fixed. How they will be fixed, however, depends on the column name and that is why each of these subs will need to be created separately.

Now, I've created the `Sub` which calls all the individual `cell` fixing `Subs`. I've also made the `Function` that tests if the corresponding `cell` contains one of the keywords. However, I can't figure out how to properly pass information about the `Array` of searchable Strings and the corresponding `cell` to the `Sub`.  I'm getting a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when I try to call the FindMatch() Function.

```
Function FindMatch(textArr() As String, cell As Range) As Boolean
    FindMatch = False
    Dim testCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

' Range.Find() each string in the Array. If one of the Strings is found, FindMatch is true
    For i = 0 To UBound(textArr)
        Set testCell = cell.Find(What:=textArr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not testCell Is Nothing Then
            FindMatch = True
        End If

    Next i

End Function
```

It is called from here:

```
Sub FindCr(cell As Range)

    Dim match As Boolean
    match = False

    Dim textArr() As String
    ' I get the type mismatch error here.
    textArr = Array("Cr", "Bag ", " Dog")

    match = FindMatch(textArr, cell)

    If match Then
' Do stuff depending on the column, for example:
        HighlightRange cell
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the main Sub that calls the individual find-and-fix Subs. It is also called from a big main loop that goes through the whole range of column name cells.

```
Public Sub fixColumnNames(cell As Range)
    'Do find-and-fix functions for all possible column names
    FindCr cell
End Sub
```

Note, I didn't want to use a ParamArray because I also need to pass the `cell` in the FindMatch() Function. I believe ParamArray is used only for when there is an undefined amount of arguments in the call. I don't want the `cell` to go in the ParamArray.

I tried changing the declarations of FindMatch and Dim textArr() to `As Variant`, but it really messes up the Range.Find() function. It started matching all kinds of wrong keywords when it was given a `Variant`. Like this:

```
Function FindMatch(textArr() As Variant, cell As Range) As Boolean
```

And

```
Dim textArr() As Variant
textArr = Array("Cr", "Bag ", " Dog")
match = FindMatch(textArr, cell)
```

So if you have an alternative approach for passing list of Strings to a Function with other additional arguments, please teach me. Or if you know what is causing the problems, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where in `FindMatch` are you getting type mismatch?

Comment: @Dean I'm getting the type mismatch when I call the ```FindMatch``` at ```match = FindMatch(textArr, cell)```

Comment: _"I didn't want to use a ParamArray because I also need to pass the cell"_. You can still do it, `ParamArray` just needs to be the last argument. `Sub fixColumnNames(cell as range, ParamArray arr() as variant)`.

Comment: _"It started matching all kinds of wrong keywords when it was given a Variant"..._ The fact that you enclosed each element in your array 'list' within double-quotes automatically makes each element a string - even when you declare as type variant. Try it, `MsgBox TypeName(textArr(0))`

Comment: As @K.Dᴀᴠɪs eludes to - you can still pass an array through to a function even with other arguments. If you were wanting to pass individual elements of that array through then I would suggest always storing that element in a type variable before passing through to avoid type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you are having issues, but this is working just fine for me. Since you were having issues with `ParamArray`, I went ahead and incorporated that into the code for demonstration purposes.

```
Sub FindCr(cell As Range)

    If FindMatch(cell, "Cr", "Bag ", " Dog") Then
        MsgBox "There was a match!"
    End If

End Sub

Function FindMatch(ByVal cell As Range, ParamArray textArr() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(textArr)

        If Not cell.Find(What:=textArr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            FindMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

I have shortened it a bit for you for readability. You never demonstrated what you were passing for your `Cell` argument, but make sure that you are fully qualifying the range.

```
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

would be an example of a fully qualified range.

Comment: @K.Davis I'm not sure why I'm having issues either, but I'm starting to suspect it has something to do with variables not having been reset properly? The cell.Find() function always returns a Range with the value "CR" for some reason, and that causes the If condition always being true. I have tried changing variable names, giving the Find() function an argument what:= "string" and searching the project for other instances of variables with same name, but I can't find anything. The Debug.Print says the Find function always returns a cell. And even restarting the program doesn't help. Wtf vba.

Comment: It returns the range with Cr value because you told it to. It’s hard coded in your array to lookup.

Comment: @K.Davis and the ```cell``` argument always gets ```Application.Selection```, and I call it by clicking a macro button. So I manually select a range, click the macro button and the program should fix the texts in the Range.

Comment: No I mean it doesn't return "Cr", it returns "CR", even when I pass the ```Function``` only a single empty cell. In that case it should definitely not return anything. There was a cell with the value "CR" in it when I did some testing for case-sensitivity yesterday, but it must have somehow gotten stuck or unreseted.

Comment: @K.Davis I tried changing the Find() part of the function. I'm always passing a single cell as ```Cell``` so I can access the value easily. I Did ```If StrComp(textArr(i), cell.Value2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            FindMatch = True ``` And it works perfectly. Find() should be doing the exact same thing, but for some reason it just doesn't. There is still something very wrong with Find(), but I'll look into it later. I've done programming with Python and Java and this kind of thing has never happened to me...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot affect an array of string in this way :

```
textArr = Array("Cr", "Bag ", " Dog")
```

To use that form of affectation, textArr must be a variant.

If you still want to use string, use redim and single affectation. For example :

```
dim textArr() as String
...
Redim Preserve textArr(1)
textArr(0) = "Cr"
...
Redim Preserve textArr(2)
textArr(1) = "Bag"
```

And so on, or you can do it in a loop or if you know the length of the final array, just Dim it with correct length

Comment: But wouldn't that make the items inside ```textArr``` Variant type? As I stated in the text, having the items as Variant type causes the ```Range.Find()``` to not work properly. Do you know how to fix that problem?

Comment: You can try modifying FindMatch() to accept variant array and convert the data to string in the loop with What:cStr(textArr(i))

Comment: I tried modifying to What:cStr(textArr(i)) and it still doesn't work. I tried debugging the values and seeing why the Find function returns a match and here's what I got:

Array value: THIS SHOULD NEVER BE TRUE
Cell value: Dont be true
FindMatch is: False
Array value: Cr 
Cell value: Dont be true
FindMatch is: True
Array value:  Dog
Cell value: Dont be true
FindMatch is: True

I legitimately don't understand what is wrong with that function, it says "Cr" is exact match for "Dont be true"...

Comment: Well, it seems that this is another problem. You do not have error 13 anymore, right ? You should exit the loop with a break when condition is encountered.

Comment: Well sort of. I knew that passing an Array of Variant can be done, but it breaks the Find function so I did not want to use it. If I give it individual String objects, the Find function works perfectly. That tells me there is still something wrong with the passed Array.